# What is the meaning of this regular expression? ['`?!\"-/]

Tags: regex

What is the meaning of this regular expression?

```
    ['`?!\"-/]
```

Why it matches parenthesis?

I used Java for development

Comment: which language you are using?

Comment: It is probably making unexpected matches because the hyphen is a special character within square brackets that defines a range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex

```
['`?!\"-/]
```

The quantity `"-/` is being interpreted as a *range* of values, just as `A-Z` would mean taking every letter between `A` and `Z`.  It turns out, by [reading the basic ASCII table](https://ascii.cl/), that parentheses lie within this range, so your pattern is including them.

One trick you can use here with dash is to place it at the *end*:

```
['`?!\"/-]
        ^^^^ this will not be interpreted as a range
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't escape the dash `-`. The dash, inside a character class `[]` denotes a range of characters. In this case from `"` to `/`. And parentheses are between those, in ASCII.

The dash needs to be escaped `\-`, if it's not the first or last character, inside a character class, when you want it to be matched as a literal.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use following
You need to escape -, otherwise, parentheses are matching.
Seems like `"-/` will include parentheses as well. Like [A-C], which matches ASCII chars between A to C

```
[\'`?!\"\-/]
```

It will match following characters in a string.

```
'`?"-/
```

Check in the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5iMzhg/2)

Comment: He is asking why it matches parenthesis

Comment: I have updated the answer, sorry for the misunderstanding.